# How to calculate CRC32 on a Python2.7 bitarray object?

Tags: python, crc32, bitarray

I could find two standard modules that support CRC32 operation on a string but when converting the bitarray to string and using it I get Unicode decode errors (as below);

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So far I tried ‘zlib.crc32(data[, value])’ and ‘binascii.crc32(data[, crc])’

Is there a module and method that does that directly on the bitarray as is?

Comment: By bitarray do you mean https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/0.8.1? But `binascii.crc32()` can compute the CRC directly on the bitarray object

Comment: You are correct!  I got confused looking at the module page and the example ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html)) showing input data to be a string ; I assume that when it writes that the module can convert binary than bitarray is included.

Thank you!